# Is there an easy way to RE-install RHEL (or CentOS or Fedora) on existing install?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, reinstall

Is there any easy way to re-install / re-build a "clean" Linux installation on top of existing partitions, etc? In other words, I'm happy with the partitions, the file system, the existing drive mounts, and KVM / VMs. I would like to do a clean reset back to the unmodified files, except for the existing file system, drives, and VMs.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: NO

---

This simple command will reinstall all the installed packages:

```
dnf reinstall --setopt=install_weak_deps=False '*'
```

However!

1. If you have extra installed files, it won't do anything about them, they will be left intact
2. It will leave intact *most* modified files in `/etc` and in some cases will install package (pristine) versions as `*.rpmnew` files, e.g. `/etc/passwd.rpmnew`.
3. Some files in `/etc` are generated/modified based on your installation settings and neither RPM, nor DNF know about that, so those `rpmnew` files might be unwise to use.

This actually sounds like a nice feature to have but AFAIK as far as Fedora/RHEL are concerned it's not present or implemented.

---

Technically you can restore all the files in `/etc`, here's how you can do it but it's **dangerous** and may leave you with a **broken** system.

1. `dnf reinstall --downloadonly --setopt=install_weak_deps=False '*'`
2. move all the RPMs from `/var/cache/dnf` to a single directory of your choice
3. Run `rpm -Uvh --force *rpm` in this directory and wait until it actually starts installing packages. Press `Ctrl+Z`
4. Run `mv /etc /etc.bak`
5. Run `resume`

When it's all done, do not forget to invoke `passwd` or you won't be able to log in. Your existing users and groups will be gone, you'll have to readd them using `useradd/adduser/groupadd`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Your insight is greatly appreciated. On the users/PWD/critical settings side, are there any certain updated files that should be saved and then restored to their original locations after reinstall?

Because Linux is so heavily CLI based, and with so many file modifications that can spin out of control, it seems the ability to "reset" would be really important.

Comment: Users and groups exist in these four files: `/etc` => passwd (list of users), group (list of groups), shadow (users shadow/users passwords), gshadow (groups shadow/groups passwords). That's pretty much it.